# Laravel 5.2 - Creating a Job API

Tags: laravel, task-queue

So in my API there are a few places where it is running a process / report that is either hitting a timeout or simply just taking WAY too long. I'd like to defer these jobs off to a queue and instead return a key in my response. The front end would then ping a service using that key to determine the status of its particular job in the queue. This way we don't have hanging ajax calls for 2 - 3 minutes. Maybe I could even create a queue viewer that would allow you to review the jobs in it and even cancel some etc.

Does Laravel have something built in or is there a package for this already? Are there other better options for dealing with this kind of issue?

Comment: A combination of https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues and https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/broadcasting is likely to suit.

Comment: except im using 5.2 which doesn't have broadcasting :)

Comment: Sure it does. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/events#broadcasting-events

Comment: I guess that might work. I was more looking for a way to have the front end ping and get a status. I get the idea of a push through a socket ....might be worth looking into.

Comment: Being able to ping for a status is going to depend on the queue driver you use and what the underlying API supports. I don't think you could do it with the SQS driver, for example. Better to use broadcasting - have the queue worker broadcast events when it starts work, progress events during the work, and completion events when done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this existed when I first posted this quesiton. However, Laravel now has this built for it: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/horizon which is everything I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

this is what you are lokking for [laravels queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues)

Comment: No, this will allow me to throw things in a queue but it doesn't help me ping whats in the queue to find the status of a job in progress.